# Change media without skipping in windows media player in .net

Tags: .net, windows-media-player

How can I do change a media in Windows Media Player component in .net **without skipping, blacked form and jumping**

I want **change a media just like seeking**(without skipping or black or jumping)

Comment: anyone don't have res response?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, this is a broad question, answer depends on context.

Comment: i must get video screen capture but i can't upload here.
open media player of windows and add two videos on play list then play first video then middle of video click on the next video.
then you click on the next until next video loaded form is black and jumping i don't won't occur this because my program is a video game. if this state occur the game not interest!